# Is a Jew permitted to use beard products to give himself the appearance of having trimmed his beard?

Tags: men-male, hair, beard

I know different communities have different standards when it comes to beards and beard care but I'm asking this from the point of view that beards are necessary and a man has restrictions on what he may do to beautify his beard.

Please take this question in the context of **"a man may not beautify himself in a way a woman does."** as being the binding rule. That is the point of view I am asking this from.

According to the above standard, is it permissible for a Jew to use beard products to give himself the appearance of having trimmed his beard?

An example of this would be the use of a beard balm or beard clay which can be used to "mold" and hold down a beard in such a way that it looks like you trimmed the cheeks. It lessens the appearance of stray hairs and prevents your face from puffing out.

- On one hand the product is preserving the beard so you get the benefit of a smoother look without damaging your beard.
- On the other hand, the act of grooming in such a way may be seen by some as violating the original standard I first mentioned. That being said, women don't have beards so the act of taking care of one's beard could possibly be an exception since it's a uniquely male activity.
- A third point to consider is whether it might violate **Marit Ayin** (the concept where a Jew should refrain from activities which appear to violate Jewish law.) *In this case the Jew is giving off the appearance he trims his beard even if he doesn't.*

I'm curious as to what the Halacha establishes as the general "best practice" for beards.

Comment: Do you know any women who beautify their beards?

Comment: @Heshy The reason I used the comparison to women is one opinion holds a Jew may not dye his beard because hair dye is something women have used to appear younger. Even though women don't have beards, the rule results in men being banned from the activity. I was asking if that same logic applies to other products.